# More idiomatic way to calculate GS1 check digit in Clojure

Tags: clojure, checksum

I am trying to calculate a [GS1 check digit](http://www.gs1.org/barcodes/support/check_digit_calculator) and have come up with the following code. The algorithm for calculating a check digit is:

1. Reverse the barcode
2. Drop the last digit (calculated check digit)
3. Add the digits together with first, third, fifth, e.t.c. digit multiplied by 3 and even digits multiplied by 1.
4. Subtract the sum from nearest equal or higher multiple of ten

It sounds simple typed out but the solution I came up with seemed a bit inelegant. It does work but I want to know if there is a more elegant way of writing this.

```
(defn abs "(abs n) is the absolute value of n" [n]
  (cond
   (not (number? n)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                 "abs requires a number"))
   (neg? n) (- n)
   :else n))

(defn sum-seq "adds (first number times 3) with (second number)"
  [coll]
  (+ 
   (* (first coll) 3)
   (second coll)))

(defn sum-digit
  [s]
  (reduce +
  (map sum-seq
  (partition 2 2 '(0) 
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %)
  (drop 2 (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/reverse s) #"")))))))

(defn mod-higher10 "Subtracts the sum from nearest equal or higher multiple of ten"
  [i]
  (if (zero? (rem i 10))
    0
    (- 10(rem i 10))))

(defn check-digit "calculates a GS1 check digit"
  [s]
  (mod-higher10 
   (sum-digit s)))

(= (check-digit "7311518182472") 2)
(= (check-digit "7311518152284") 4)
(= (check-digit "7311518225261") 1)
(= (check-digit "7311518241452") 2)
(= (check-digit "7311518034399") 9)
(= (check-digit "7311518005955") 5)
(= (check-digit "7311518263393") 3)
(= (check-digit "7311518240943") 3)
(= (check-digit "00000012345687") 7)
(= (check-digit "012345670") 0)
```

Comment: are you happy to accept an answer? (I am a beginner and worked hard on my one!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defn check-digit 
  [s] 
  (let [digits        (map #(Integer/parseInt (str %)) s)
        [chk & body]  (reverse digits)
        sum           (apply + (map * body (cycle [3 1])))
        moddiff       (mod (- 10 sum) 10)]
       moddiff))
```

This implementation uses two clojure idioms I am conscious of:

- `let` to manage local decomposition (and reuse)
- `map` with a second collection, being an infinite lazy sequence 'adjacent' to the problem.

Also de-structures list so that would be easy to write the checking predicate as `(= moddiff chk)`.

Comment: Head straight to 4clojure!

Comment: Can you expand on why/how this answers the question?

Comment: @Denomales this is my re-implementation of the questioner's main function check-digit which passes his tests and is hopefully more 'idiomatic', although I am not an expert. It certainly is shorter!

Comment: thanks. I'm not at all familiar with coljure, but your solution does look much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Threading macros -> ->> are pretty great at chaining function applications

(defn to-digits [s] 
     (map #(Integer/parseInt (str %)) s))

```
(defn check-digit [string]
 (->> string
   to-digits
   reverse rest
   (map * (cycle [3 1]) )
   (apply +)
   (- 10)
   (#(mod % 10))
   ))
```