# Efficient implementation of the GTIN-13 algorithm

Tags: r, performance, checksum, check-digit

I am looking for an efficient way to implement the [GTIN-13 check digit algorithm](https://www.gs1.org/services/how-calculate-check-digit-manually). I have looked at some relevant SO posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921814/more-idiomatic-way-to-calculate-gs1-check-digit-in-clojure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043300/how-to-calculate-checksum-digit-for-ean-14) but it seems like efficiency was not the subject of attention in either case.

Briefly, the algorithm takes a numeric string (such as 123765) and multiples every other digit (from right to left) by 1 or 3 to calculate a sum (so `5 * 1 + 6 * 3 + 7 * 1 + 3 * 3 + 2 * 1 + 1 * 3 = 44`) and then subtracts this sum from the closest multiple of 10 that is equal to or greater to this sum (in this case `50 - 44 = 6`) to derive the final check digit (here, 6). The input is expected to be 12 digits long, but if shorter, it can be simply padded with zeros from the left (so `123765` is really expected as `000000123765`) but the result will be still the same.

A naive implementation of this would be as follows:

```
gtin13 <- function(n) {
  s <- as.character(n)
  check.sum <- 0
  for (i in 1:nchar(s)) {
    digit <- substr(s, nchar(s) - i + 1, nchar(s) - i + 1)
    check.sum <- check.sum + as.numeric(digit) * ifelse(i %% 2, 1, 3)
  }
  10 - check.sum %% 10
}
```

However, this is inefficient because of the for loop as well as the conversion to a string and back to a number. For instance:

```
df <- data.frame(
  num <- sample(1:1000000, 100000, T)
)
system.time(cd <- vapply(df$num, gtin13, 0))
```

Take about 6 seconds on an average desktop.

What is a more efficient to calculate this check.sum?

Comment: You should use Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version doesn't need the vapply so it's faster because we don't loop over the number of possible digits in R. For example

```
gtim13_vec <- function(x) {
  d <- x %% 10
  for(i in 1:12) { # Input can be up to 12 digits
    d <- d +(x%/% 10^i %% 10) * c(1,3)[1+i%%2]
  }
  d
  10-(d%%10)
}
```

I used `set.seed(7)` for this experiment. I see

```
system.time(r1 <- vapply(df$num, gtim13, 0))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.21    0.00    3.36 
system.time(r2 <- gtim13_vec(df$num))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.00    0.03 
all(r1==r2)
# [1] TRUE
```

So there's a big speed improvement.

Comment: This is a great solution.  I had a feeling this could be vectorized.

Comment: Why would you call this vectorization? It still involves a for loop (just like vapply).

Comment: It’s only dosing that inner loop once. A vapply is basically just a different way of writing a loop. So it reduces something that is more like a double loop to something that is a single loop. The vectorized + is faster than any apply version.

Comment: Got it. The other issue is you are hard-coding 1:7 here; can we replace it with `1:ceiling(log(x)/log(10))` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Using Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

int gtim13_cpp(int x) {

  int r, sum = 0, coeff = 1;
  while (x != 0) {
    r = x % 10;
    sum += coeff * r;
    coeff = 4 - coeff;  // 3 <--> 1
    x /= 10;
  }

  return 10 - (sum % 10);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector gtim13_all_cpp(IntegerVector x) {

  int n = x.size();
  IntegerVector res(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res[i] = gtim13_cpp(x[i]);
  }

  return res;
}


/*** R
gtim13_all_cpp(123765)

gtin13 <- function(n) {
  s <- as.character(n)
  check.sum <- 0
  for (i in 1:nchar(s)) {
    digit <- substr(s, nchar(s) - i + 1, nchar(s) - i + 1)
    check.sum <- check.sum + as.numeric(digit) * ifelse(i %% 2, 1, 3)
  }
  10 - check.sum %% 10
}
df <- data.frame(
  num <- sample(1:1000000, 100000, T)
)
system.time(cd <- vapply(df$num, gtin13, 0))
system.time(cd3 <- gtim13_all_cpp(df$num))
all.equal(cd3, cd)
*/
```

Results:

```
> system.time(cd <- vapply(df$num, gtin13, 0))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.105   0.001   4.105 

> system.time(cd3 <- gtim13_all_cpp(df$num))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.003 

> all.equal(cd3, cd)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do much better. If we operate on integers instead of characters, we see a great gain in efficiency:

```
gtim13Challenger <- function(n) {
    n <- as.integer(n)
    len <- as.integer(ceiling(log10(n)))
    digs <- n %/% as.integer(10^(0L:(len - 1L))) %% 10L
    if (len > 1L)
        digs[seq.int(2L,len,2L)] <- digs[seq.int(2L,len,2L)] * 3L
    10L - sum(digs) %% 10L
}

system.time(cd <- vapply(df$num, gtim13, 0))
user  system elapsed 
6.15    0.00    6.16 

system.time(cd2 <- vapply(df$num, gtim13Challenger, 0L))
user  system elapsed 
0.76    0.00    0.76 

all.equal(cd, cd2)
[1] TRUE
```